# OnClickListener not working on a TextView in canvas

Tags: android, textview, clickable

I have added a TextView to a canvas object programatically but the OnClickListener is not working for the TextView. I have looked at other answers and I have tried debugging using LogCat but not able to find the problem.

EDIT 1: I am drawing Canvas and TextView multiple times i.e. I have multiple TextViews that I wanted to get displayed at some X and Y and I drew those using Canvas, updating the code. Making the edit as I believe may be the multiple canvases are interfering with each other.

This is the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<texts.length;i++){

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setText(texts[i]);

    layout.addView(textView);
    layout.measure(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    layout.layout(0,0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    c.translate(x1[i], y1[i]);
    layout.draw(c);
    textView.setClickable(true);
    Log.e("DebugClicker","BeforeClickable");
    textView.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("DebugClicker","Clicked");
            Intent sIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+text));


            sIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


             try{
                    startActivity(sIntent);
                }
                catch (SecurityException e){
                    Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
            Log.e("DebugClicker","AfterClickable");
        }
}
```

Comment: try setting the orientation of `layout` ie your linear layout..

Comment: How will that solve the issue?

Comment: may be it couldnt draw the textview due to it..

Comment: textView is showing but its not clickable. Also, I tried to add orientation to the layout (both Horizontal and Vertical) but it didnt work :(

Comment: @user3667569 Did you find the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
textView.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: Could it be you draw something over the textview and you can't click it for this. If you try "textView.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);". It could solve the problem

Comment: updated some details, would appreciate if you can pls take a look.

Comment: What do you do with the `layout` later?